# editorInfo not resetting upon pressing home button Android

Tags: android, editor, back-button, android-homebutton

I have two different editors and I am differentiating them based on the variable `editorInfo.privateImeOptions`. Each editor has a different value set for this variable. When I open an editor and press the back button and then open another editor, everything works fine. But if I open an editor, press home button and open another editor, `editorInfo.privateIMEOptions` still gives me the old value i.e the value associated with the first opened editor but not the one newly opened. Is there a way to flush `editorInfo` or make the home button work exactly like the back button on android.

It would also be helpful if anyone could let me know how to make home button work like back button in android.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the Back and the Home keys is that when the Home key is pressed, the `Activity` is moved to the back of the activity stack whereas the Back key removes it from the activity stack (which essentially means the `Activity` is finished).

To emulate the Back key behavior for a Home key press, you will need to finish the `Activity` when it is sent to the back of the activity stack. Please take a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

You could try the following in your `Activity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```